# Upvotes have two different values?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Well, see this picture to know what I am asking.

[image]

Why does this happen, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Is one of those a question and the other an answer? Answers get +10 and questions +5 per vote.

Comment: Oh, make that an answer and you get free rep.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers get +10 rep per vote and questions get +5 per vote. We consider answers to have more value than questions.